# EF Core not setting class variables automatically

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I want to switch my code to an async implementation. When I want to do this then I notice that my related data gets not set automatically after I retrieve them like it used to do it.
This is the initial function that gets called from an API controller. I used the `AddDbContext` function to add the dbcontext class via dependency injection into my controller:

```cs
public async Task<Application> GetApplicationById(AntragDBNoInheritanceContext dbContext, int id)
{
    List<Application> ApplicationList = await dbContext.Applications.FromSqlRaw("Exec dbo.GetApplication {0}", id).ToListAsync();
    Application Application = ApplicationList.First();
    if(Application != null)
    {
        await CategoryFunctions.GetCategoryByApplicationID(Application.Id);
    }
}
```

The `GetCategoryByApplicationId` function loads the related category of an application which is a many to one relation between `Category` and `Application`:

```cs
public async Task<Category> GetCategoryByApplicationID(int applicationID)
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AntragDBNoInheritanceContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ApplicationDBConnection.APPLICATION_CONNECTION);
    using (var dbContext = new AntragDBNoInheritanceContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
    {
        List<Category> category = await dbContext.Categories.FromSqlRaw("Exec GetApplicationCategory {0}", applicationID).ToListAsync();
        if (category.Any())
        {
            return category.First();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I want to retrieve an application then the field `Category` is not set. When I did not use async/await it would set the category automatically for me. Of course I could just return the `Category` Object from the `GetCategoryByApplicationId` and then say:

```cs
Application.Category = RetrievedFromDbCategory;
```

But this seems a bit unmaintainable compared to the previous behaviour. Why does this happen now and can I do something about it? Otherwise I don't see much benefits on using async/await .

Comment: Why are you executing SQL code instead of e.g. `dbContext.Applications.First(x => x.Id == id);`?

Comment: @Tvde1 Because I have stored procedures in my database that I want to use. Also this is not the topic.

Comment: Just so I get it right, the previous behavior was that if you fetched an `Application`, the reference to `Category` would be null, and if you later coincidentally fetched the category from the database, `Application.Category` would also be filled with the fetched category. And this isn't happening anymore?

Comment: @Tvde1 The other way around. Before switching to an async implementation the related `Category` would be set automatically every time. Not coincidentally. Now when I switched to the async method this beheviour is not present anymore. Is that understandable?

Comment: You forgot `await` while calling `CategoryFunctions.GetCategoryByApplicationID(..)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tested it with await still the same. I even had it with await just forgot to copy it inot here, I'll correct it

Comment: I do not understand why it should set something automatically? Assign application.Category property explicitly. EF do not fixup navigations between two different context instances.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Try to build something similar and you will see please. I have no assignments whatsoever in my code and all the related data gets set properly without async. My assumption on why this is happening is that I dont pass my dbcontext to the `GetCategoryByApplicationId` function but instead I now create a new dbcontext connection with the using statement. I have to do this because otherwise I get the error that the dbcontext is being used while another thread is not finished with it etc

Comment: Ensure that you do not create two DbContexts. EF do not fixup navigations between different context instances.